# How to change a class variable into an ordered variable in R?

Tags: r, anova, p-value

Hey guys I am trying to calculate the p value of individual variables to see if they have an impact when the other variable is set to 0. Here is my code:

```
quiet_result = aov(overbearing ~ as.factor(Intention)*as.factor(quiet_only), data=df)
summary(quiet_result)

loud_result = aov(overbearing ~ as.factor(Intention)*as.factor(loud_only), data = df)
summary(loud_result)
```

For context, the intention variable only has the values of -1 and 1. -1 is intentional and 1 is intentional. Quiet_only and loud_only are new columns created from a data set. quiet_only only has the values of 0 and 2 and it is the original column of sound + 1, and loud_only only has the values of -2 and 0 because it is only the original column of sound - 1. Therefore these are all ordered variables and they are not supposed to be assessed by their actual numerical value like a class variable. However, my code keeps reading it as a class variable even though I changed all the variables to factors to make them ordered variables. Therefore, when I run anova on them, they all return the same result. I am wondering how I can change the variables to make them into ordered variables because the anova is only reading the change between the intention and quiet_only/loud_only columns, which would obviously return the same anovas because there is no actual change if you subtract or add 1 to a column. Therefore, I'm trying to find the p value of the intention variable with loud_only and quiet_only and this p value should change depending on whether I use loud_only or quiet_only.

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense lol. This is research work for a graduate professor so it uses concept that I don't fully understand (I'm undergrad) so I don't think I explained it very well. Anyways, if any of you have any ideas that would be great.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide a demo of your data, then the community is easier to image the issue and give solutions. Maybe this link helps https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Use `dput` to share with us at least a small part of your data. We can better understand what you are trying to achieve and maybe someone will be able to help you then.